# After a Glassfish update got javax.servlet.ServletException: <f:ajax> contains an unknown id - cannot locate it in the context of the component

Tags: jsf, glassfish

I have a code:

```
<h:panelGroup id="panel" layout="block">
    ...
    <!-- in a button -->
    <f:ajax ... render=":panel" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

And I have an error: javax.servlet.ServletException:  contains an unknown id ':panel' - cannot locate it in the context of the component j_idt378. It worked before an update of glassfish. How to fix it? What for is this?

h:panelGroup is root element (inside a page that uses ui:composition template), so I don't know what to write before :panel.

Comment: What jsf Version are you using previously ans what Version now? Also you should provide the Code related to your problem

Comment: I used 2.2.4. And still I use it (manually replaced javax.faces.jar), but this error still exists.

Comment: As answered in the duplicate, look at generated HTML output, not at JSF source code in order to figure the right client ID. The rules are not different in templates.